# JS Convert a string into a json object

Tags: javascript, json

Need to turn a string into a json object.

---

Rules for json object / string:

1. each iteration is incremented by one.
2. split('|'), this is each row in the json object.
3. split('^'), this is each field in the row.
4. split('~'), this is each subfield in the field.
5. needs to account for not having a subfield, field, or row
6. Needs to run in Internet Explorer 11, pre ES6

---

```
String Example:
var str = "1863707152859270^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:25:52 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070|1863707222859280^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:27:02 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070"
```

---

Attempts:

```js
 var str = "1863707152859270^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:25:52 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070|1863707222859280^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:27:02 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070"
function ParseDelimList(str){
      var result=[];
      var rows = str.split('|');
    
      var tmpString3 = [];
      for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        var fields = rows[i].split('^');
    
        var tmpString2 = [];
        for(var j=0;j<fields.length;j++){
          var subfields = fields[j].split('~');
    
          var tmpString1 = [];
          for(var l=0;l<subfields.length;l++){
            var tmp1 = "{"+l+":"+subfields[l]+"},"
            tmpString1.push(tmp1);
          };
          var tmp2 = "{"+j+":"+tmpString1[j]+"},";
          tmpString2.push(tmp2);
        };
        var tmp3 = "{"+i+":"+tmpString2[i]+"},";
        tmpString3.push(tmp3);
      };
      return tmpString3;
    };
    
console.log(ParseDelimList(str))
```

---

End result (something like this):

```
var json = [
  "1":{
    {"0":"1863707152859270"},
    {"1":"Exercise to lose weight"},
    {"2":"289169006"},
    {"3":"Reduce 20 pounds"},
    {"4":"Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner."},
    {"5":"5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM"},
    {"6":"1/21/2019 4:25:52 PM"},
    {"7":"Y"},
    {"8":"Frank the Tank"},
    {"9":"1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM"},
    {"10":"1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM"},
    {"11":"Frank the Tank"},
    {"12":"Abnormal LGSIL"},
    {"13":"1848065703239670"},
    {"14":"1863707006859070"},
  },
  "2":{
    {"0":"1863707152859270"},
    {"1":"Exercise to lose weight"},
    {"2":"289169006"},
    {"3":"Reduce 20 pounds"},
    {"4":"Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner."},
    {"5":"5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM"},
    {"6":"1/21/2019 4:25:52 PM"},
    {"7":"Y"},
    {"8":"Frank the Tank"},
    {"9":"1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM"},
    {"10":"1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM"},
    {"11":"Frank the Tank"},
    {"12":"Abnormal LGSIL"},
    {"13":"1848065703239670"},
    {"14":"1863707006859070"},
  }
];
```

Comment: Sounds like HL7! Now what have you tried already? Because you will get downvoted if you don't provide your own attempts. SO is not there so people can write your code for you.

Comment: You're question is so unclear, please, provide more information, some examples...

Comment: Don't create JSON strings by hand. Create arrays and objects, and at the end using `JSON.stringify()` to convert the whole thing to JSON.

Comment: He's not creating them by hand @Barmar. He is almost certainly reading them from a stream and now wants to convert them to JSON.

Comment: @seesharper I'm talking about things like `var tmp2 = "{"+j+":"+tmpString1[j]+"},";` That's creating JSON by hand, and it's also invalid.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: @seesharper is correct.

Comment: @Barmar I see - yes you are right. Not the best approach.

Comment: Do you really want an array of objects, where each object has a different numeric key, like `[{1: value}, {2: value}, ...]`? That's not usually useful, and it's also not valid JSON. Keys have to be in double quotes, and if the value is a string it also needs quotes.

Comment: The problem is that messages in this format (is this HL7 @Frank?) do not provide keys. Instead you get a field name that is derived from its location in the message. For instance "PID-3-1" for the first subfield of third field of segment PID. How do you propose to get the values for the keys?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Well, the incoming is from an API call from software from GE Healthcare. there is multiple calls that output this type of format. Trying to make this generic enough to be usable on all calls then push the results to a different function. I am no JSON expert so if you all have suggestions on what the output should look like after converting the string. i am ok with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, ready to be `JSON.stringify`'d. Triple `split` followed by `map` gets you there:

```js
var str = "1863707152859270^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:25:52 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070|1863707222859280^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:27:02 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070";

var result = str.split('|').map(x => {
  return {
    row: x.split('^').map(y => {
      return {
        field: y.split('~').map(z => {
          return {
            subfield: z
          };
        })
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

As you are not totally clear in your expected outcome, please let me know if anything is missing.

**Edit**: Added the same solution compatible with IE 11 below:

```js
var str = "1863707152859270^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:25:52 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070|1863707222859280^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:27:02 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070";

var result = str.split('|').map(function(x) {
  return {
    row: x.split('^').map(function(y) {
      return {
        field: y.split('~').map(function(z) {
          return {
            subfield: z
          };
        })
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You need ES6 for those arrow functions. What version of JS are you running?

Comment: Running on Angular 1.7.7 and JQuery 2.1.1, Needs to run on IE11 which i believe is what is causing the error

Comment: Well I assumed changing an arrow function to an ES5 function wouldn't impose to high of a barrier to cross for you. Added that for you just in case. `map` is part of ES5 and as such, supported even by IE 11.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: you don't really want all those objects with key:value pairs where the key is simply the index. Your data will be easier to work with (and reflect the source structure better) if you simply have arrays of arrays (of arrays).

```
var str = 'FOO^one|BAR|TEST^one^two^a$b$c^three';
var obj = str.split('|')
        .map(s => s.split('^')
            .map(x => x.split('$')));

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I am unable to use due to the issue of map not running in IE11. Is there an alternative to .map() , with your elegant solution?

Comment: A few ways to go. You can use the lodash library which has the function _.map(), or you can use an ES6 to ES5 transpiler, which let's you use ES6 syntax and convert to ES5. Or you an rewrite it fairly simply using for loops instead of .map. Remember that .map is just a convenient shortcut. You can do the same thing with a plain for loop over the result of .split().

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce split and map.

```js
var str = "1863707152859270^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:25:52 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070|1863707222859280^Exercise to lose weight^289169006^Reduce 20 pounds^Walk daily for one hour. Have a light dinner.^5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM^^1/21/2019 4:27:02 PM^Y^Frank the Tank^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^1/22/2019 8:50:02 AM^Frank the Tank^Abnormal LGSIL^1848065703239670^1863707006859070"
function ParseDelimList(str){
  return str.split(/[|]+/).reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
    op[index]= inp
              .split(/[\^]+/)
              .map((e,i)=>({[i]:e}))  //change this if needed
    return op
  },{})  
};

console.log(ParseDelimList(str))
```

I don't see `~` in provided input so i didn't included in answer.

you can just change the map incase you have `~` in input.

`.map((e,i)=>({[i]:e.split(/[~]+/).map((e,i)=>({[i]:e})}))`

Comment: Code Maniac, i am having a syntax error when trying to add the '~'

```JS
    function ParseDelimList(str){
      return str.split(/[|]+/).reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
        op[index]= inp
        .split(/[\^]+/) 
        .map((e,i)=>({[i]:e
          .split(/[~]+/)
          .map((e,i)=>({[i]:e}))}) //.map((e,i)=>({[i]:e}))
        return op
      },{})  
    };
```